# How can i show a activity indicator in table view when i scroll table view to the bottom like in Flipkart in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

UITableView always shows an indicator in a footer.
I want to load more items from server when my table view scroll to bottom of the View.

My code is:

```
UIView *loadMoreV = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, homeTV.frame.size.width, 40)];
loadMoreV.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
loadMoreV.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;

UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
activityIndicator.alpha = 1.0;
activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(loadMoreV.frame.size.width/2,20);
activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = NO;
[loadMoreV addSubview:activityIndicator];

homeTV.tableFooterView = loadMoreV;
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Comment: do u have solve ur prob on  activity indicator in table view when i scroll table view to the bottom like in Flipkart in ios. if yes u can update ur answer by posting and other could get benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a check in CellforRow TableView method to get the last row and fetch data from server in that check.

Comment: i want to show it like in flipkart. with a loader showing loading items